# dynamically masking a pandas df to find rows that match strings from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

Hi All I have the following code: I would like to make my script more dynamic by changing the "hi" to a variable that will mask if any of the strings inside my_list are in the df. The project that I am working on the my_list could have up to 50 elements.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First Column Name':  ["Hi", "lo"],
        'Second Column Name': ['Hi', 'lo']})

my_list = ["Hi", "med"]

mask = np.column_stack([df [col].str.contains("hi",flags=re.IGNORECASE ,na=False) for col in df])
x = df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
print(x)
```

Return:

```
First Column Name Second Column Name
0                Hi                 Hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
m = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(my_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(1)
x = df[m]
Out[30]: 
  First Column Name Second Column Name
0                Hi                 Hi
```

Comment: Do you know if there a way to adapt
 m = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(my_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(1) 
so that you can use it on non strings too? with most of my df it works but some cause an error 

Can only use .str accessor with string values! 

I am not in a position really to transform the whole column to a string although I could transform the rows with these characters to strings